# allow all users to read/write any files/folders on 2nd drive regardless of who created it

Tags: mount, permissions, samba, disk

I am running 14.04 LTS. I've got a mount point called `/files` that is owned by `root`, the group is `plugdev` and I've given the group write permission. I used some of the information in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive to set this up. Specifically the following commands:

```
sudo chgrp plugdev /files
sudo chmod g+w /files
```

All the users on the machine are also part of `plugdev`.

I've mounted a drive that has 1 `ext4` partition to it.

At this point both `user1` and `user2` **can** create files/folders in `/files`. But, if `user1` creates a file or folder in `/files` then `user2` **cannot** modify it or create files in it.

**I am wondering, how can I make it so all users can read/write (and, where applicable, execute) any/all files/folders created in `/files` regardless of who created it.**

If it matters, `/files` is also a Samba share that is mounted on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: I recommend downloading this free PDF: http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxcommand/files/TLCL/13.07/TLCL-13.07.pdf/download and reading Chapter 9: Permissions, particularly the section at the end on "Special Permissions".  A combination of the setgid bit, the sticky bit, and a proper umask setting for your group members, should solve your situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to create is a "world-readable" mount...  Not very secure, but if that's what you want, you should not only allow the `g`roup, but also the `u`ser and `o`thers to `r`ead and `w`rite.  Ideally, you would also like to do that for the already existing files `recursively`

So change:

```
sudo chmod g+w /files
```

to:

```
sudo chmod --recursive ugo+rw /files
```

**However:** absolutely, positively *don't come back here to whine and complain* after one of the users deletes the entire directory structure of another user to make space to store his/her/its collection of pr0n.

### ;-)